# "To show that f is injective" - I don't get this statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose that f: A -> B.

To show that f is injective: Show that if f(x) = f(y) for arbitrary x, y element A with x != y, then x = y.

Why does this defintion(?) of injective state that one of the conditions for it to be true is that x != y and then conclude that x = y.

I am confused on that part. Unless it means the "indexes" of x and y are != but the actual values are. I just don't get it.

Another thing that is confusing to me is the use of the same symbol that has just been introduced to me from propositional logic. Is the arrow operator meant to indicate this is a conditional function?

Comment: This is completely beyond my comprehensive powers.

Comment: Where did you get that "definition"? It makes no sense. The correct definition is: $\;f\;$ is injective iff $\;f(x)=f(y)\implies x=y\;$

Comment: Hint: the passage "x != y, then x = y" looks suspect. Also please type `$x\neq y$` to get $x\neq y$; readers of this site are not generally programmers.

Comment: @Timbuc: it *does* make sense, it is equivalent to the definition of injectivity. It is extremely strange, though.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. This is my first question here and I am not quite sure how to produce the math symbols. I'll pick it up soon enough I am sure.

Comment: @FPE, I can't see the sense: it says it must be shown that if $\;f(x)=f(y)\;$ **and**  $\;x\neq y\;$ , then $\;x=y\;$ .

Comment: @Timbuc For injective functions, "$f(x)=f(y)$ and $x\ne y$" is always false, so the whole statement is true by [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth). It is a bit silly and I don't think it helps the OP, but formally, FPE's answer below is not incorrect.

Comment: Still, is redundant. I know, any false statement ==> *any* statement (false or true), but in this set up it is, to say the least, silly, as it is not an exercise in logic.

Comment: @Timbuc: to say that something "makes no sense", it ought to really make no sense, in my opinion. I dare say that sometimes, redundance is helpful when writing statements. Of course in this case this is not true, but still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This definition is in fact equivalent to the standard one:
$$(\star) \quad \forall x,y\in A, f(x)=f(y) \Rightarrow x=y.$$

I'll show the equivalence. Suppose that $(\star)$ holds. We want to show that if $f(x)=f(y)$ and $x\neq y$, then $x=y$. Since we have $f(x)=f(y)$, we have by $(\star)$ that $x=y$, i.e. we already have the result. What this really means is that we always have $(A\text{ and } B)\Rightarrow A$, whatever $B$  is.

Conversely, suppose that $f$ is injective with your definition. Our goal now is to show $(\star)$. For this, let $x,y\in A$ be so that $f(x)=f(y)$. Let us do a case analysis: if $x=y$, then we have the conclusion of $(\star)$, and we are done. Otherwise $x\neq y$. By your definition of injectivity, we have $(f(x)=f(y)\text{ and } x\neq y)\Rightarrow x=y$, so that again, $x=y$, as required.

Comment: Awesome explanation. I can only pretend to understand it right now but I am gonna study this for awhile. It's up to me now. Thank you.

Comment: Although this is a neat observation that boils down to $$(A \implies B) = (B \lor \lnot A) = (B \lor (\lnot A \lor B)) = ((A \land \lnot B) \implies B),$$ I don't think it will help (actually it might confuse further) someone who is encountering the definition of injective for the first time.

Comment: @angryavian: Yes, and I am sure that this is actually a typo in the original text. This answer is only here to show that this is not "non sense", as some comment/answer claimed it was.

Comment: @FPE ack, You have shown it to be true with your parent post and at the same time you say this is more than likely a typo in the textbook? LOL. Now, I am confused. Should I change the accepted answer?

Comment: @Bradley If you want the definition of injective, use the one on Wikipedia / in my answer. What FPE is showing is that _technically_, the "nonsensical" definition in your post is equivalent to the definition of injectivity that everyone uses (just as _technically_, the statement "all nonzero numbers whose square is zero are blue" is true simply because the square of a nonzero number is nonzero). Regardless, no one uses the definition given in your post.

Answer (score 2):

The [usual definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function#Definition) does not include "with $x \ne y$."

> A function $f:A\to B$ is injective if for any $x,y \in A$, if $f(x)=f(y)$, then $x=y$.

I'm not sure where you got the definition that you wrote, but it does not make sense...

Comment: I didn't think so either. It's from a math book. Must be errata. Thank you for clearing this up.

Comment: @Bradley: note that even if this definition is a bit strange, it is in fact equivalent to the standard one. Nothing prevents to do such strange things in first-order logic.

Comment: Okay, thank you. It is very counter-intuitive to me but if you say its correct then I will keep studying it. Thank You.

Comment: @Bradley: see my answer to see why the definitions are equivalent. Also, please accept the answer that you like the most, so that this question leaves the "unanswered" list.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a silly merger of the usual definition: $f(x) = f(y)$ implies $x = y$, for all $x,y$ in the domain, with the alternative definition (contrapositive): if $x \neq y$ for $x,y$ in the domain, $f(x) \neq f(y)$.